# 1 is being added in the output while calculating the value of "e" iteratively

Tags: java, math

I'm writing a program that Computes E. All is well and done except the value of E being outputted starts with "3." instead of "2." I have no idea what is causing this and I'm sure it is something stupid. Should be something simple, but apparently I'm too blind to find it.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal; //To use for calculating E

public class ComputeE {

    /*  * The number of trailing numbers after the decimal  */
    public static final int PRECISION = 18; 

    /*  To Prevent Rounding Errors  */
    public static final int PRECISION_OFFSET = 4;   


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*            * Declare and initialize variables    */
    BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal(0.0);                 //E to be returned

    int iterations = 0;                                 //Counter for iterations required       

    /*            * Process for computing factorial     */

    for(int i = 0; i < PRECISION + PRECISION_OFFSET; i++)
    {
        iterations++;
        BigDecimal numerator = new BigDecimal(1.0);                                                 // Setting Numerator
        BigDecimal factorial = new BigDecimal(calcDenominator(i));                                  // Calculating Denominator
        factorial = numerator.divide(factorial, PRECISION + PRECISION_OFFSET, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); // Compute The Factorial                                                            
        e = e.add(factorial);                                                                       // Add The Factorial to E           

    }

    e = e.setScale(PRECISION, e.ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //Cut Off Extra Digits

    /*            * Console Output  */
    System.out.println("Computed value of e : " + e);
    System.out.println("Expected value of e : " + Math.E);
    System.out.println("Required Iterations : " + iterations);

}//End of main

public static double calcDenominator(int n)
{
    /*            * Declare and initialize variables    */
    double denominator = 1.0;                       //Start the BigInt with 1

    /*            * Calculate Denominator   */
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)                      
    {
        denominator = denominator * i;              // Multiply BigInteger by the BigInteger obtained with the int value i
    }
    return denominator;

} //End Method

}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing the factorial in the right way in your `calcDenominator` method. Change the for loop condition of your `calcDenominator` method from

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```